# How to avoid generic in hierarchy of classes?

Tags: java, oop, generics

I have next hierarchy of classes

```
   class MyObject {

}

class FirstChild extends MyObject {

}

class SecondChild extends MyObject {

}

class Calculator<T extends MyObject> {
    public Integer calculateValue(T supperObject) {
        return 10;
    }
}

class IntegerCalculator extends Calculator<FirstChild> {
    @Override
    public Integer calculateValue(FirstChild supperObject) {
        return super.calculateValue(supperObject);
    }
}

class SecondChildCalculator extends Calculator<SecondChild> {
    @Override
    public Integer calculateValue(SecondChild supperObject) {
        return super.calculateValue(supperObject);
    }
}


class AbstractUsefulService {
    protected Calculator<? extends MyObject> calculator;

    public AbstractUsefulService(
        Calculator<? extends MyObject> calculator
    ) {
        this.calculator = calculator;
    }
}

class ImplementationOfAbstractUsefulService extends AbstractUsefulService{

    public ImplementationOfAbstractUsefulService(
        SecondChildCalculator calculator
    ) {
        super(calculator);
    }

    public void doJob(){
        calculator.calculateValue(new SecondChild());
    }
}
```

I have a big problem here  calculator.calculateValue(new SecondChild()); - required ? extends MyObject but found SecondChild. I've read a lot of articles and found only one solution and a generic to AbstractUsefulService and use this generic in ConnectionService, but I don't want to do it. How can I resolve my problem without generic in AbstractUsefulService?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I resolve my problem without generic in AbstractUsefulService?

You can't, if you are going to pass the `calculator` to `AbstractUsefulService`.

You need to know what type of object the `calculator.calculateValue` will accept.

The only way to do it would be to keep a reference in the `ImplementationOfAbstractUsefulService` class:

```
class ImplementationOfAbstractUsefulService extends AbstractUsefulService{
    private final SecondChildCalculator secondChildCalculator;

    public ImplementationOfAbstractUsefulService(
        SecondChildCalculator calculator
    ) {
        super(calculator);
    }

    public void doJob(){
        secondChildCalculator.calculateValue(new SecondChild());
    }
}
```

Comment: But why? I specify that `calculator.calculateValue` accepts any implementation of MyObject and it doesn't meter which one. what is wrong with this approach ?

Comment: "I specify that calculator.calculateValue accepts any implementation" No, you've specifed that it takes a *specific* implementation, but you just don't know which one. See [What is PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)